# Sticky table header inside scrollable box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I'm currently experimenting with sticky table headers inside a relative complex setup.

**I want the table header to stick beneath the main header** if the scrollContainer is scrolled down without loosing the ability to scroll horizontally inside the box:

[image]

The Problem is, that the table container is horizontal scrollable and the outside container "scrollContainer" is also scrollable vertically. To make things even more interesting there is also a static main header ;-)

**Is there a jQuery-Plugin out there, that can handle this use case** or is there a other solution for this?

```js
$('table.floatthead').floatThead({
  responsiveContainer: function($table) {
    return $table.closest('#scrollContainer');
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 3em;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

#scrollContainer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lightgray;
  height: calc(100% - 3em);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

section.content {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: darkgray;
  padding: 1em;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.box .header {
  background: yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box .content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 600px;
    background: orange;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

th {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/2.0.3/jquery.floatThead.min.js"></script>
  <header>Main Header</header>
  
  <div id="scrollContainer">
    <section class="content">
      
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Boxheader</div>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="floatthead">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Country</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
              <td>Maria Anders</td>
              <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
              <td>Francisco Chang</td>
              <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ernst Handel</td>
              <td>Roland Mendel</td>
              <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Island Trading</td>
              <td>Helen Bennett</td>
              <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
              <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
              <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Boxheader</div>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="floatthead">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Country</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
              <td>Maria Anders</td>
              <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
              <td>Francisco Chang</td>
              <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ernst Handel</td>
              <td>Roland Mendel</td>
              <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Island Trading</td>
              <td>Helen Bennett</td>
              <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
              <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
              <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is not so clear. Do you want the <div id="scrollContainer"> to use the 100% of the horizontal space?